# jQuery - if selected option contains string, change value of other field

Tags: jquery, indexof

Like the title says, what I'm trying to do is: If the selected (dropdown) option contains a certain string, I want to change the value of another field. Normally I would just do this with a switch, but the values of some of the dropdown options are the same (they're part of a bigger form combination and I can't directly edit the options because it's a generated form).

Currently it's not working. This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#ballform_programid').change(function(e) {
    var sel = $('#ballform_programid')[0];
   message_index = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

  if (message_index.toLowerCase().indexOf('barbara') >= 0){
                $("#ballform_campusid").val('403');
});

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<select name="programid" id="ballform_programid" class="pf_dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose one</option>
    <option value="63">degree at Santa Barbara</option>
    <option value="63">degree at Ventura</option>
    <option value="76">Online degree (M.L.S.)</option>
</select>

<input name="campusid" id="ballform_campusid" value="00" />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/cW55R/7/)

Comment: What's this doing `var sel = $('#ballform_programid')[0];`?

Comment: @j08691: It's getting the DOM element object from the jQuery object.

Comment: @Guffa - ah right. I tend to use .get().

Comment: You have a syntax error, you are missing the closing `}` for the `if` statement.

Comment: There needs to be a rule that you're not allowed to post a JS question unless you've checked your Javascript console for syntax error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a missing moustache after the `ìf`. I inserted it and Fiddle worked fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ballform_programid').change(function(e) {
        var sel = $('#ballform_programid')[0];
        message_index = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

        if (message_index.toLowerCase().indexOf('barbara') >= 0){
            $("#ballform_campusid").val('403');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, use jQuery:

```
$('#ballform_programid').change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).find(":selected").text().toLowerCase().indexOf('barbara') >= 0) $("#ballform_campusid").val('403');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cW55R/9/)**